# Right-to-left when using webkit-column

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to get right-to-left scrolling/content when using `-webkit-column`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it's not possible for now, the columns take the entire width of the container but enlarge it or its children hides the overtaken content without showing any scrollbar, even with overflow:auto.
Hope it will be fixed soon if I am not mistaken !